# Invoke-WebRequest - store request content even on error?

Tags: powershell, http, error-handling

I am using Powershell's `Invoke-WebRequest` (this also applies to `Invoke-RestMethod`) to make a call to an ElasticSearch cluster. This specific command often returns an error result (`409 conflict`).

Powershell sees the error state, throws an error and does not pass anything useful through the pipeline, and it spews the body of the response onto the console:

[image]

However, a) even though it's got an error code, I don't really care that it's errored (only that it's returned), and b) I want to be able to access the body of that response so that I can actually inspect the data contained within.

Is there any way to have PowerShell suppress the error output (`-ErrorAction` does not work) and pass something useful along the pipeline?

As a note, I actually want to invoke this with `Invoke-RestMethod` but as it and `Invoke-WebRequest` are essentially the same command, I've generalised this question to `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `Invoke-WebRequest`, you have to go deeper and use `System.Net.WebRequest` directly, I think I have some code somewhere where I do exactly what you need, is that an option?

Comment: Totally an option, if you have something you can share. I don't want you to bother writing something just for this though.

Comment: Beginning with PowerShell 7 Microsoft has added a `-SkipHttpErrorCheck` parameter to `Invoke-WebRequest`. Ref: [Invoke-WebRequest # -SkipHttpErrorCheck](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last year I wrote a script to diagnose common IIS setup problems, it's on [GitHub](https://github.com/hahndorf/Test-WebSite), for it I needed to analyse the response from the server, even for non-200 results, especially for non-200 results, so `Invoke-WebRequest` didn't work.

I removed some stuff and the essential code is below.

I use the .NET `System.Net.WebRequest` because even if a `System.Net.WebException` is thrown, you can still access the response-stream with reponse headers and the body.

```
$url = "http://localhost"

try {
    $r = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $r.UserAgent=$userAgent
    $resp = $r.GetResponse()        

    Write-host "Response Headers:" 
    foreach ($HeaderKey in $resp.Headers) {
            $caption = $HeaderKey.PadLeft(15," ")
            Write-host "$caption`: $($resp.Headers[$HeaderKey])";
    }                            

    $reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
    $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream
    $body = $sr.ReadToEnd()
    Write-host "$body"

    $resp.StatusCode 
}           
catch [System.Net.WebException] 
{              
    $resp = $_.Exception.Response

    if ($resp -eq $null)
    {
        Write-host $_.Exception
    }
    else
    {
        $reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
        $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream
        $body = $sr.ReadToEnd()

        Write-host -Text "Response Headers:" 
        Echo "         Status: $([int]$resp.StatusCode) - $($resp.StatusCode)"
        foreach ($HeaderKey in $resp.Headers) {
                $caption = $HeaderKey.PadLeft(15," ")
                Write-host "$caption`: $($resp.Headers[$HeaderKey])";
        }
        Write-host "$body"

        $resp.StatusCode                
    }                    

} catch {            
    Write-host  $_.Exception
}
```